# Query returns nothing on matrixBlock

Tags: matrix

I'm a bit confused by the way that Craft now handles Matrix blocks. I've read the documentation a few times and I'm still not sure if I have it.

Here's what I have:

```
{% set myMatrixBlockQuery = craft.matrixBlocks().ownerId(4).type('block__artists') %}
{% set matrixBlocks = myMatrixBlockQuery.all() %}
{% for block in matrixBlocks %}
  <li>{{ block.id }} / {{ block.artistName }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But all that gets output is:

```
8 /
9 /
10 /
```

Where `10` (etc) is the ID of the block. It's not outputting the artistName despite that field existing and having content. Is my query wrong?

Comment: is your artistName field a plaintext field? What outputs when you do `{{ dump(block) }}` inside your loop?

Comment: Yeah it's a plaintext field. The output I get mostly all seem to be attributed as NULL which is weird. One of the only fields that isn't is the ID field. Full output is here: https://pastebin.com/EFQp64Ya — this is looped over 3 times

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add the fieldId() param to your query as per https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1789